# Examples of non abelian powerful p-groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, examples-counterexamples, p-groups

Let $p$ be a prime number. For a group $G$ and a positive integer $m$, let $[G,G]$ denote the commutator subgroup of $G$ and $G^{m}=\langle g^{m};~g\in G\rangle$.

It is well known that a finite $p$-group $G$ is called a powerful $p$-group if either $p\neq2$ and $[G,G]\leq G^{p}$ or $p=2$ and $[G,G]\leq G^{4}$. Clearly, all abelian finite $p$-groups are also powerful $p$-groups since $[G,G]=1$, but these are the trivial examples and then non interesting.

In the book "Analytic Pro-$p$ Groups, 2nd edition, is proven in the page 44 the following theorem:

**Theorem.** Let $G$ be a finite $p$-group of rank $r$. Then $G$ has a characteristic powerful subgroup whose index is bounded by a function of $p$ and $r$.

The subgroup constructed in the proof of this theorem is $V(G,r)$, if $p\neq2$ and $V(G,r)^2$ if $p=2$, where $V(G,r)$ is the intersecction of the kernels of all homomorphisms from $G$ to the General Linear Group $GL$$_{r}(\mathbb{F}_p)$. Of course, it is not immeadiate to found this subgroup and I think that this subgroup may be the trivial subgroup.

Then, how to obtain a finite non-abelian powerful $p$-group? Is there a known presentation of a non abelian powerful $p$-group for each prime $p$?

Comment: Rather than delete your previous question and then post the same question now with context, the expected behavior is to edit the previous question, then request that it be re-opened  in the corresponding [meta thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/32975/742).

Comment: For reference, [here's the deleted post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4300686/742) for those with sufficiently high reputation.

Comment: [*Powerful $p$-groups I. Finite groups*](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021869387902110) by Alexander Lubozky and Avinoam Mann, J. Algebra **105** no. 2 (1987) pp. 484-505.

Comment: For each odd prime $p$ there exist a non abelian powerful $p$- group of order $p^3$.